# Dotfuscator not rename variables and method

Tags: obfuscation, dotfuscator

I made a simple `exe` program, configured Dotfuscator Professional Edition and started `Build`. Dotfuscator created a `Dotfuscated` folder containing a new `exe` file. I opened the new `exe` in DotPeek and there I can see exactly the same code as I wrote.

[image: DotPeek result after running Dotfuscator Professional]

Earlier I also tried to use the free Dotfuscator Community version and got some kind of obfuscation.
[image: DotPeek result after running Dotfuscator Community]

What have I done wrong? Why does the free version work as expected while the professional does not?

Comment: I work for the Dotfuscator team. DotPeek might be finding your source file on disk and using that; note that in the Assembly Explorer, you can see renaming obfuscation has been applied (the actual name of the shown class is `eval_z`). Try adding a comment to your source file, recompiling, re-running Dotfuscator, and checking if DotPeek shows you the comment. Also, your second image doesn't appear to be from the free Dotfuscator Community, as Control Flow obfuscation seems to be present.

Comment: @JoeSewell I did exactly what you say and seen my comment in DotPeek. `https://imgur.com/a/sILdKdS`

Comment: @JoeSewell  I also copied my `exe` file to other folder and rename it. after all manipulation dotPeek has shown obfuscation like this :: `https://imgur.com/a/U13tdAH`

Comment: @JoeSewell Looks like `dotPeek` open other files. why ?

Comment: still have no idea

Comment: I can't speak to why DotPeek looks for source files when possible. But based on your response, and I believe there was a self-answer here sometime today, is the question about Dotfuscator resolved?

Comment: @JoeSewell yes, please write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotPeek makes an effort to find the original source files on your computer when possible, using information contained in the debugging symbol files (`.pdb` files). This is especially noticeable if comments from the source show up in DotPeek, as the assembly (protected with Dotfuscator or not) never includes these comments.

Deleting these `.pdb` files should show the obfuscated code that's actually in the assembly.

(Note that I am a developer on the Dotfuscator team.)